# SimpleHTTPServer figure not displayed

Tags: html, simplehttpserver

I'm using the SimpleHTTPServer (invoked in a folder `output`):

```
python -m SimpleHTTPServer 8080
```

I have the following folder structure:

```
/output/
   images/
       figure.svg
   index.html
```

In `index.html` (among other things):

```
<div class="figure align-right">
   <object data="images/figure.svg" type="image/svg+xml"></object>
   <p class="caption">Some caption.</p>
   <div class="legend">Something</div>
</div>
```

Now I view `index.html` on `http://127.0.0.1:8080/index.html` and the figure is NOT displayed. Why? The server finds the file as it gives no `404` code.

The funny thing is that when I open `index.html` in the browser as a local file (not through the http server) the image appears.

I'm using `Opera` if that matters.

Comment: 2 minutes of googling got me this : http://gotmetoo.blogspot.fr/2013/07/python-simple-http-server-with-svg.html . could be what you are looking for

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested in the comments, find solution here:
http://gotmetoo.blogspot.fr/2013/07/python-simple-http-server-with-svg.html